# Find Window Associated with a ViewModel in WPF and MVVM/MVVMLight

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

Is there a smart way for me to find out what WPF Window is associated with what ViewModel?

I'm currently building a dialog service and I need to set the owner to a specific window. I'm currently hardcoding the `.Owner` property to `Application.Current.MainWindow` but I thought I'd check here to see if someone had done something similar and had a smart of doing this.

Would one way be, to associate the `Window` type to the ViewModel in a dictionary using the ViewModel as the key in my ViewModelLocator when it is initialized? But then what?

Assuming my MainViewModel calls the following code

```
_dialogService.ShowDialog(settingsWindowViewModel);
```

I would like to pass one of the properties of my `SettingsWindowViewModel` as such:

```
SettingsWindowViewModel settingsWindowViewModel = new SettingsWindowViewModel
{
    Title = "Settings",
    Owner = "MainViewModel" or //this;
}
```

and in the definition of the DialogService, the `ShowDialog` would be defined as such:

```
public bool? ShowDialog(IDialogWindowViewModel dialogViewModel)
{
   var win = new WindowDialog
   {
      Title = dialogViewModel.Title,
      Owner = GetWindowByViewModel(dialogViewModel.Owner);
   }
}
```

Where the GetWindowByViewModel will access the dictionary that contains the Window types, but I'm not sure how to get the actual window, as I'll only have the 'type'.

```
return App.Locator.ViewModelLocator.GetWindowByViewModel(owner);
```

Where owner is the ViewModel associated with a specific Window type.

I've seen something similar to the above in a project that was using `Unity`, but a) I can't recall where I saw this, and b) I'm using `MVVMLight` rather than `Unity`.

Any suggestions on to handle such a scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with my own suggestion.

Here's the breakdown:

1. Add a Dictionary of  to the ViewModelLocator to store the ViewModel type and the Window Type.

   ```
   public static Dictionary<Type, Type> WindowTypes;
   ```

   NOTE: Make sure the ViewModelLocator is available to the entire app by defining a public static field in the ViewModelLocator class.

   public static ViewModelLocator Instance => 
   Application.Current.Resources["Locator"] as ViewModelLocator;
2. Add the Window type and ViewModel type to the WindowsTypes dictionary defined above in any windows that will require to display a dialog box and that will need to act as a parent window.

   ```
   public MainWindow()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       this.Loaded += (s, e) =>
       {
           // register window type to corresponding viewmodel
           ViewModelLocator.WindowTypes.Add(this.DataContext.GetType(), 
           typeof(this.GetType());
       };
   }
   ```

   NOTE: The use of 'this.DataContext.GetType()' will always work in my scenario as I'm defining all my ViewModels in XAML:

   ```
   DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator},
   Path=MainWindowViewModel}"
   ```
3. Finally, there's the DialogService definition:

   ```
   public bool? ShowDialog(IDialogWindowViewModel dialogViewModel, object parent)
   {
       var win = new WindowDialog
       {
           Title = dialogViewModel.Title,
           BtnAccept = {Content = dialogViewModel.AcceptButtonText, 
           Command = dialogViewModel.AcceptButtonCommand},
           BtnCancel = {Content = dialogViewModel.CancelButtonText, 
           Command = dialogViewModel.CancelButtonCommand},
           SizeToContent = dialogViewModel.SizeToContent,
           Width = dialogViewModel.Width,
           Height = dialogViewModel.Height,
           WindowStartupLocation = dialogViewModel.WindowStartupLocation,
           DataContext = dialogViewModel,
           Owner = GetWindowByType(parent.GetType())
       };
       return win.ShowDialog();
   }
   ```

As you can see, the `parent` parameter type will be used to identify the relevant window which is done in the GetWindowByType function:

```
private Window GetWindowByType(Type type)
{
    if (ViewModelLocator.WindowTypes.ContainsKey(type))
    {
        return Application.Current.Windows.Cast<Window>().FirstOrDefault
        (window => window.GetType() == ViewModelLocator.WindowTypes
        [type]) ?? App.Current.MainWindow;
    }
    else
    {
        return App.Current.MainWindow;
    }
}
```

NOTE: You might notice the failsafe, if it fails to find the relevant ViewModel type in the Dictionary, or if for some reason if fails the relevant window when looping through all available Windows in the WPF app, it will return the Main Window.

Hope this helps.